# UIView frame not resizing with containing UIScrollView

Tags: objective-c, uiview, uiscrollview, orientation, frame

I have a UIScrollView containing a UIView subview. These both fill the entire window. I set this up in IB.

In my code I have this:

```
- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews {
[super viewDidLayoutSubviews];
[self.fullViewScroller layoutIfNeeded];
self.fullViewScroller.frame = [self.view convertRect:self.fullViewScroller.frame fromView:nil];
CGRect newViewInScrollViewFrame =  CGRectMake(0, 0, self.fullViewScroller.frame.size.width, self.viewInScrollView.frame.size.height);
//self.viewInScrollView.frame = newViewInScrollViewFrame;
self.fullViewScroller.contentSize = newViewInScrollViewFrame.size;
NSLog(@"fullViewScroller.frame.size.height: %.2f; fullViewScroller.frame.size.width: %.2f", self.fullViewScroller.frame.size.height, self.fullViewScroller.frame.size.width);
NSLog(@"fullViewScroller.contentSize.height: %.2f; fullViewScroller.contentSize.width: %.2f", self.fullViewScroller.contentSize.height, self.fullViewScroller.contentSize.width);
NSLog(@"viewInScrollView.frame.size.height: %.2f; viewInScrollView.frame.size.width: %.2f", self.viewInScrollView.frame.size.height, self.viewInScrollView.frame.size.width);
}
```

The problem I'm having is that when I change the orientation to landscape, the viewInScrollView trailing edge is no longer in contact with the scrollView and maintains its landscape width. I've tried changing the frame size (see the commented out code) and adding constraints but I can't get it to work.

Does anyone have any ideas of what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks for any help offered.

Comment: what are the layout constraints you added?

Comment: Trailing and Leading edges of UIView to superview (UIScrollView)

Comment: It seems this line was the issue:

self.fullViewScroller.frame = [self.view convertRect:self.fullViewScroller.frame fromView:nil];

I removed it and the constraints are much happier.